# What is the difference between Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What is the difference between these two api ?

- Azure AD Graph API
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog
- MS Graph API 
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview

Comment: Did you read this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) from microsoft already ?

Comment: @MichaelHufnagel useful. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Microsoft Graph** supports most of the directory features that **Azure AD Graph** supports, but not all.

Here is some information for you to refer.

1.The two APIs have different endpoints.

- MS graph : graph.microsoft.com
- AD Graph : graph.windows.net

2.Client libraries

- AD Graph client library is only available for .Net applications and it is maintenance mode.
- MS Graph client libraries are available on multiple platforms and languages, that enables you to have more choice in how you can use directory data in apps for your customers.

3.For more gaps between Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph, you could refer to this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

**Note**: The time of the article is **May 10, 2017**, you could refer to [Changelog for Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog) to see some feature was or not been updated.

Comment: is that correct saying "The two APIs have different endpoints" in the answer ?

Comment: @InfoÁsith Yes, I am sure it is correct, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart#how-to-construct-a-graph-api-url) for AD graph, and the [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview) you mentioned for MS graph.