# Is it possible to get all the user informations in a tenant by Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

From the [Azure Active Directory v2.0 authentication libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) we can see lots of samples about how to use libraries to connect Active Directory. It seems all of them should create an application at [apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) first. Then use the `Application ID` and a new password to act the `clientID` and `clientSecret` in a client or server middleware application.

This way, one user can use the application to login by oauth 2 or openid through the `Azure Active Directory API`. Also can get the personal information such as user profile correctly.

But, if I want to get all the users information in a tenant one time, is there an API can do?

Comment: look into [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api), [APi Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, if I want to get all the users information in a tenant one time,
>   is there an API can do?

You can use Microsoft Graph API - specifically [List Users API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

For a quick test, try using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

---

Similarly you can list users with Azure AD Graph API as well, but it would be **recommended to use Microsoft Graph API**.

Read [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) and this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834133/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-ad-graph-api-and-microsoft-graph-api) (Only case to use Azure AD Graph API would be if you need something very specific that you aren't able to achieve with stable version of the newer Microsoft Graph API.)

Azure AD Graph API to list users (not recommended)

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), it just returned one user(me) but there has another user in my tenant. I have checked `user.read.all` permission. What else need to do?

Comment: User.Read.All is a permission that requires Admin consent.. if you're able to give yourself that permission without any issues, then I would have expected it to work.. I'm sure this is the right API and it works in my case listing all users.. but may be I'm missing something on the permissions..

Comment: Another thing to check, I hope you aren't using a Microsoft account.. something like Zhang@outlook.com or live.com etc... If that is the case, try using an account that belongs to the specific Azure AD (or it's verified domain) like xyz@mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Thank you. I can get all `users` by app now.

Comment: Would it give the userList even after the tenant is deleted for next few hours ? I need to delete the all user related data once the tenant is deleted

Comment: @biswpo I don't think you should even be able to delete the directory if you have multiple users and their info still present.. so ideally there should not be a question about getting `userList even after the tenant is deleted for next few hours`. Please take a look at the Microsoft Docs here.. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto#prepare-the-directory it says.. `There can be no users in the directory except one global administrator who is to delete the directory. Any other users must be deleted before the directory can be deleted.`

Comment: Is directory same as Tenant ?

Comment: @biswpo yes it’s the same