# AD Graph API get calendar details

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I need to pull down calendar details with AD graph API. How do I achieve this ?

I see lot of example with Microsoft graph API but not for AD graph API. Any pointers ?

Looking for API end point documentation for https://graph.windows.net to pull down 
the calendar details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, AAD Graph API does not support to get the calendar. See all the AD Graph APIs here: [Azure AD Graph API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog). The MS Graph API and AD Graph API are different, they will have some features different from each other.

In the official doc, Microsoft strongly recommends that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API. They are no longer updating the content of AD Graph API regularly and Microsoft Graph is where they are investing for Microsoft cloud services.

As you may have found, you could use MS Graph API : [Get calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) to do that. Besides, for more details about the difference between MS Graph API and AD Graph API, see this link : [What is the difference between Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834133/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-ad-graph-api-and-microsoft-graph-api).

Comment: Thank you, so in your opinion what should be used Office 365 API or Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: @user1005310 I have mentioned in my reply, you could use this api:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0