# Graph API Response: Could not find a property named 'telephoneNumber' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Contact'

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm receiving the response "Could not find a property named 'telephoneNumber' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Contact'" from my API call.

I've tried other fields that work just fine such as jobTitle, in this list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference

My API call uses a bearer token and is in the following format:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{MY CONTACT ID}}/contactFolders/{{ FOLDER ID HERE}}/contacts?$select=displayName,fileAs,emailAddresses,businessPhones,mobilePhone,homePhones,department,telephoneNumber&top=999
```

I would expect for telephoneNumber to be part of the response, but I get an error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API that you are calling is Microsoft Graph API(`https://graph.microsoft.com`), the link you provided is the [`Contact Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#contact-entity) in Azure AD Graph API(`https://graph.windows.net`). The two APIs are different, difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834133/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-ad-graph-api-and-microsoft-graph-api). In your case, you need to check [`contact resource type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) in Microsoft Graph, obviously, there is no `telephoneNumber` property.

Comment: So is getting a list of custom data not do-able with the graph api?

Comment: @BestDevTutorials You can get custom data, but not include some properties like `telephoneNumber`, which is not a property of `contact` object in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @BestDevTutorials Maybe you can try the azure ad graph api - [Operations on contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/contacts-operations), but I am not sure if it meets your requirement.